# USB sticks and video devices not recognized

Tags: mount, usb-drive, lsusb

For the last 3 days, USB sticks that I plug in my laptop don't mount and video devices have disappeared from /dev.
The USB stick is recognized as a USB device but not as a storage device and doesn't mount.

My built-in webcam (/dev/video0) isn't listed in /dev anymore. Neither are USB webcams that I've tried to plug in.

I think this is an issue with my Ubuntu rather than my USB sticks as this is happening both with my SanDisk 32GB usb stick and a micro SD card mounted on a USB adapter. 
Also when I dual boot using Windows on the same machine, the USB sticks are recognized by Windows.

I have tried formatting the USB stick but that didn't solve the issue. The stick data format is FAT and the partition map is a Master Boot Record.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, kernel # is 3.13.0-142-generic

Here are the details of the commands I've tried:

**Mount**

```
sudo mount /dev/bus/usb/002/009 /mnt
mount: /dev/bus/usb/002/009 is not a block device
```

**Lsusb**

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58ea Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**syslog: "is not an MTP device"**

```
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.129347] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.223238] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5590
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.223249] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.223255] usb 2-1.2: Product: Ultra
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.223261] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 kernel: [ 6643.223266] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 4C530001190505101540
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
Mar 20 14:46:38 clem-Ideapad-Z570 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
```

**fdisk: device not detected**

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x24597e9e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      411647      204800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          411648   806082472   402835412+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       806082558   945829887    69873665    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       945829888   976773167    15471640   12  Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda5       806082560   929628159    61772800   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       929630208   945829887     8099840   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

**blkid: stick not detected**

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1A4611084610E5F3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="54CE1264CE123F24" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="LENOVO_PART" UUID="107418177417FE62" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="36f138fc-139e-49e7-a6f1-15a0f57ee53f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="4e5635fc-82a5-43ce-81d8-fe20838965ba" TYPE="swap"
```

Any thoughts on what's happening?

Comment: But both of the sticks work on Windows/Mac?

Comment: Yes, both work on Mac (haven't tried on Windows)

Comment: What model is your laptop?

Comment: My laptop is an Ideapad-Z570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just solved my own problem: I installed the latest package updates, did a reboot and now my usb sticks and video devices are recognized.
Not sure what was happening exactly but problem solved.